# prove that two integers are in the same remainder class mod n provided that they have the same remainder when divided by n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, proof-explanation

prove that two integers are in the same remainder class mod n provided that they have the same remainder when divided by n.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, and since they have the same remainder when divided by n, this implies that $\exists s,t \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $a=sn+r,b=tn+r \implies$ $ a \equiv r \ mod \ n,b \equiv r \ mod \ n \implies a \equiv b \equiv r \ mod \ n$.therefore, $$a,b \in \mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z} $$

Is this proof valid?

Comment: You define a remainder class as a set of elements which have the same remainder in respect to a specified $n$. So, in this case, you're done.

Comment: @ Alberto Andrenucci thanks! perhaps I should end it with "therefore $$a \equiv b$$?

Comment: Sure. You say, if you want to be formal, a definition:

$a \equiv b \mod n \iff a$ has the same remainder of $b$ in respect to $n$.

So, yes.

Comment: @ Alberto Andrenucci please take a look at my newly edit. and let me know if it is better now.

Comment: You should've stopped saying that $a \equiv b \equiv r \mod n$. If you are working in $\mathbb{Z}$ when you talk about the quotient, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ you are simply considering the equivalence classes in respect to $n$.

So you can always consider an element in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ just by identifying it with is equivalence class. In fact, you can consider the function $\pi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ which sends an element $x$ in his remainder in respect to $n$. His remainder is in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score -2):

Formal answer.

**Definition**: Two integers are equivalent$\mod n$ if they leave the same remainder when divided by $n$. We say $a \equiv b \mod  n$ if $a$ and $b$ are equivalent.

So, when you've proved that they have the same remainder, you can easily conclude that they're equivalent.